# how can i stop phaser sprite after reaching moveToPointer location?

Tags: phaser-framework

What i am trying to accomplish is to have a user click on the canvas and the sprite(player) will move to that location and STOP once it reaches that location.

Currently i have the player can click and it will continue in that path which is the default function.

```
update: function() {
    this.player.rotation = this.game.physics.arcade.angleToPointer(this.player);
    if (this.game.input.activePointer.justPressed()) {
        // move on the direction of input
        this.game.physics.arcade.moveToPointer(this.player, this.playerSpeed);
    }
}
```

Maybe its simpler than i think but i cant seem to find a solution.
point in the right direction would be useful :)

Answer (score -1):

I think you look for something like this:

- Using **[Tweens](https://phaser.io/examples/v2/tweens/chained-tweens)** (something very interesting about Phaser)

  **OR**
- Using
  **[Arcade Physics](https://phaser.io/examples/v2/arcade-physics/move-towards-object)** (which is an example similar to yours)